# Как остановить генерирование жидкости на определенном фрейме в Blender

Tags: blender

Возможно, вопрос слишком глупый и простой и плохо гуглил. В Blender сцене есть fluid domain и inflow, который генерирует воду. В сцене 250 фреймов, и мне нужно что бы на 110 фрейме inflow прекратил генерировать воду. Как это сделать?

Answer (score -1):

В настройках физики есть вкладка Bake, там указывается диапазон кадров